# take placeholder from resources with html tags

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-placeholder

There is simple string in my resource file `"Good Day,Sir <br /> Have a nice day."`.This string must be a placeholder on TextArea.But html tags don't work.I'm trying to use Html.Raw but it doesn't help.what should i do?

```
  @Html.TextAreaFor(model => Model.Text, 15, 5, new { @placeholder = reviewPlaceholder, @class = "span12", @style = "resize: vertical;" })
```

Comment: You can't do it, placeholder attribute cannot have line-break neither HTML code http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html#textarea.attrs.placeholder

Comment: thx for helping =( so its impossible to format placeholder text?

Comment: I gave it a try and it works, but you have to use the new line characters not HTML code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, although the specs says that user agents should strips new lines from the placeholder, I did a test in Chrome and it accepts new lines. You'll have to replace the `<br />` by `/r/n`:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => Model.Text, 15, 5, new { @placeholder = reviewPlaceholder.Replace("<br />", "\r\n"), @class = "span12", @style = "resize: vertical;" })
```

I can't assure you this will work forever because it's not in accordance with the specs, but todays it's working.

I did more tests: works in all major brwosers but Firefox.